# Error: use of deleted function when adding element to a map in C++

Tags: c++11, g++

I'm getting a wall of text when I try to compile my code using g++ 11 in a Linux environment. I've tracked the cause of the error to one line of code where I'm trying to add elements to a map. Here's some of the relevant code:

```
set<Tuple> trash;
Relation garbage(trash, name, scheme_list);
Relations.insert({name, garbage});
```

Where the Tuple and Scheme classes (scheme_list is of type Scheme) are both simply `vector<string>`. The Relation class is defined as

```
public:
    Relation(set<Tuple> TUPLES, string NAME, Scheme SCHEMES);
    ~Relation();
```

and the Relation constructor is

```
Relation::Relation(set<Tuple> TUPLES, string NAME, Scheme SCHEMES)
{
    Tuples = TUPLES;
    Name = NAME;
    Schemes = SCHEMES;
}
```

The intent of the code at the moment is to create an empty set of Tuples, use the existing name in `name` and the list of schemes in `scheme_list` to create an instance of class `Relation` to insert into my map of `Relations` using the name as the key. Yet when I compile the code, it gives me a gigantic list of "use of deleted function" errors and "Relation::Relation(const Relation&) is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed", the latter being the only reference to any of my code given by the compiler. What is causing this error, and why does it only occur when I try to insert elements into a map?

Comment: Class `Relation` has some data members (of which you show none) that are not copyable, which renders the whole class non-copyable, too. However, you are trying to make a copy of `garbage`, an object of type `Relation`. Hence the error.

Comment: You should add the entire code of `class Relation`. You could also try to reproduce a minimal "non-working" example using e.g. [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com).